# Nextjs not logging console.log or console.error when running with "next"

Tags: webpack, next.js

So I have this logs in my `server.js` file:

```
  console.info("LOOGGGGGSSSS")
  console.warn("LOOGGGGGSSSS")
  console.log("LOOGGGGGSSSS")
  console.error("LOOGGGGGSSSS")
```

My `package.json` has script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "start": "next start"
  }
```

When I run server with npm run start all works correctly and I can see logs but with `npm run dev` no `console.log()` or `console.error()` works at all.

I tried with option quiet true and false but still not working:

```
const nextJsApp = next({dev, quiet: false}); // no logs in terminal
```

and

```
const nextJsApp = next({dev, quiet: true}); // still no logs in terminal
```

My `next.config.js`

```
require("dotenv").config();
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const apiKey =  JSON.stringify(process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY);

module.exports = withCSS({
    webpack: (config) => {
        const env = { SHOPIFY_API_KEY: apiKey };
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));
        return config;
    },
});
```

Comment: The `next` command does not run your `server.js` file. If you want to run `server.js`, run `node server.js`. More information here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Answer (score 37):

Go to the terminal where you ran `npm run dev`.
You should be able to see your console log there.

Comment: but i want to see it in chrome console

Comment: @Getzel The whole point of a server side component / server side rendering (`getStaticProps`) is that any JavaScript logic is performed on, well, the server, **before it gets to the client**. So if you want to see it in your browser, you have to call `console.log` in your client side logic.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to see your server logs in local development mode, you do not need to use your own server. You can edit the dev Script in your package.json like this:

```
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
```

and when you run your dev (`npm run dev`) you can go in Chrome to: `chrome://inspect`.

At the bottom under remote target, click on `inspect`.

Comment: not working for me: 'NODE_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: In Windows you need to use the `cross-env` package to be able to set the NODE_OPTIONS variable, as seen in the answer by waliby.

Answer (score 4):

I used the package cross-env to avoid some issue when working with different OS.

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
```

Works just fine, I can now see all my logs mixed with Next logs.

[See this in the official Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging#debugging-on-windows).

Answer (score 4):

I think it's cause you have to use "use client"

if your using next.js 13, every component is a server side component by default which means the component won't run on the browser, if you want to use client side components write "use client" on the top of your file.

but I won't recommend putting "use client" on top just because you want the information to display in the browser you can see this link to learn more about client side and server side components https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log` info is on the terminal.

Open your OS terminal, look at your terminal, you will see the `console.log` data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this from my `next.config.js`. I figured it only applied for production, but maybe not.

```js
    removeConsole: {
      exclude: ["error"],
    },
```

I will add this to `tsconfig.json` instead:

```json
"removeComments": true,
```

Answer (score -1):

As [@AryanJ-NYC mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240340/nextjs-not-logging-console-log-or-console-error-when-running-with-next#comment108342685_61240340), when using a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in Next.js you'll need to update the scripts in `package.json` to run the `server.js` file.

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
}
```